# Class isn't being added to element when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a Joomla site and I'm making the category description accordion according to the position of H3 headings the editor places in the WYSIWYG editor.

So far I've got this simple function (clearly it needs a little tidying):

```
jQuery('.category-desc h3').addClass('accordionheading').nextUntil('.category-desc h3').hide();
jQuery('.category-desc h3').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('activeaccordionheading').nextUntil('.category-desc h3').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).removeClass('activeaccordionheading').siblings('h3').nextUntil('.category-desc h3').slideUp();
});
```

and everything works just fine except the "activeaccordionheading" class is not being added to relevent h3 when it is clicked. Any ideas why?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RuRhw/)

**Edit...**

A schoolboy error! I was removing the class as soon as having added it when what I was trying to do was remove the class from its siblings!

```
jQuery(this).removeClass('activeaccordionheading').siblings('h3').etc...
```

should be

```
jQuery(this).siblings('h3').removeClass('activeaccordionheading').etc...
```

Comment: But...you're adding it then removing it in the next line immediately?

Comment: Gah! You're absolutely right :-)

Comment: Thanks for the extra pairs of eyes guys - I'd been staring at this code for ages and not seeing the answer staring me in the face!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the class `activeaccordionheading` on siblings try this by adding removeClass after `siblings()`:

```
$(this).siblings('h3').removeClass('activeaccordionheading').nextUntil('h3').slideUp();
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RuRhw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are removing that class right after you add it with the following line of code:

```
jQuery(this).removeClass('activeaccordionheading').siblings('h3').nextUntil('.category-desc h3').slideUp();
```